# My solution to optimizing a utility function does not agree with the textbook answer.

Tags: optimization, economics, utility

I have a problem from an economics course. I worked out a utility function to be given by $$ U (F, C_1) = \ln C_1 + \beta \ln F + \frac{\ln ((1+r)\left( V_1 + w(1-\tau)(1-F) - C_1\right))}{1+\phi}$$
and I need to maximize this function w.r.t. $F$ and $C_1$

The final answer is supposed to be

$C_1 = \tilde\theta (V_1 + w(1-\tau))\quad $  where $\displaystyle \tilde \theta = \frac {1+\phi}{1+(1+\phi)(1+\beta)}$

$ F = \displaystyle\frac{\beta C_1}{w(1-\tau)}$

But my solution seems to have

$\displaystyle \tilde \theta = \frac {(1+\phi)^2}{1+(1+\phi)(1+\beta(1+\phi))}$

$\ $

My working is as follows:

$\displaystyle 0=U_{C_1}=\frac 1{C_1} - \frac 1{( V_1 + w(1-\tau)(1-F) - C_1)(1+\phi)}$

$\implies\ C_1 = ( V_1 + w(1-\tau)(1-F) - C_1)(1+\phi)$

$\implies\ C_1 = \displaystyle\frac {V_1 + w(1-\tau)(1-F)}{2+\phi}$

$\ $

$0=U_F = \beta \displaystyle \frac1F -\frac{w(1-\tau)}{( V_1 + w(1-\tau)(1-F) - C_1)(1+\phi)}$

$\implies\ Fw(1-\tau) = \beta ( V_1 + w(1-\tau)(1-F) - C_1)(1+\phi)$

Substituting in:

$Fw(1-\tau) = \beta \left( V_1 + w(1-\tau)(1-F) - \displaystyle\frac {V_1 + w(1-\tau)(1-F)}{2+\phi}\right)(1+\phi)$

$\hspace{4em} =\beta\displaystyle\frac{(1+\phi)(1+\phi)\left(V_1 + w(1-\tau)(1-F)\right)}{2+\phi}$

$\hspace{4em} =\beta\displaystyle\frac{(1+\phi)(1+\phi)(V_1 + w(1-\tau))-Fw(1-\tau)(1+\phi)^2}{2+\phi}$

$Fw(1-\tau)\left(1 + \displaystyle \frac{\beta (1+\phi)^2}{2+\phi}\right)=\displaystyle\frac{\beta(1+\phi)^2\left(V_1 + w(1-\tau)\right)}{2+\phi}$

$\ $

Do you see where the mistake lies?

Answer (score 1):

My error lies in the following step:

$C_1 = (V_1 + w(1-\tau)(1-F) - C_1)(1+\phi)$

$\implies\ C_1 = \displaystyle\frac {(V_1 + w(1-\tau)(1-F))(1+\phi)}{2+\phi}$

$\ $

In any case, a quicker method would be to realise that $$0 = U_F = \frac{\beta}F - \frac {w(1-\tau)}{C_1}$$ and then move on from there.